# Is it possible to use group() in combination with ArrayOperators.arrayOf() in Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Given the data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b7fb9acdcf58886fa86136"),
    "cost" : 50,
    "nodes" : [ 
        4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b7fba3cdcf58886fa86137"),
    "cost" : 25,
    "nodes" : [ 
        1, 2, 3, 4, 23, 6
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b7fbaecdcf58886fa86138"),
    "cost" : 75,
    "nodes" : [ 
        1, 2, 17, 19, 20, 21
    ]
}
```

I can use aggregation in MongoDB to group by the second element in the array like this:

```
db.stuff.aggregate([
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$nodes", 1]},
    "costs": {$sum: "$cost"}
  }
}])
```

In Spring Data MongoDB, I ended up using the following Java code to get the same result:

```
Aggregation aggTest = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    project()
        .and(ArrayOperators.arrayOf("nodes").elementAt(1)).as("node")
        .and("cost").as("cost"),
    group("node").sum("cost").as("costs")
);
```

Is it possible to use group() in combination with ArrayOperators.arrayOf().elementAt in Spring Data MongoDB, therefore removing the additional project()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Group stage in spring mongo db doesn't take `AggregationExpression` for `_id`.

You can try to create a `AggregationOperation`

```
AggregationOperation group = new AggregationOperation() {
      @Override
      public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return new BasicDBObject(
                "$group", new BasicDBObject(
                  "_id", new BasicDBObject(
                    "$arrayElemAt", Arrays.asList("nodes", 1))).append(
                "costs", new BasicDBObject("$sum", "cost")));
       }
    };

Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(group);
```

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear, but thanks for for the alternative. I'm gonna look into why Group doesn't take AggregationExpression for _id.